# Youtube embed video does not work in test server

Tags: jsp, url, enfinity

In Enfinity environment, I want to determine whether my website now is running on HTTP or HTTPS. My method is to get the URL using `request.getRequestURL().toString();` then test whether the string has `https://` or not. The URL in the address bar is like this:

```
https://test.example.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/Example-ExampleSite/en_US/-/USD/Pipeline-Start
```

But, the result of the code is like this:

```
http://test.example.com/servlet/Beehive/WFS/Example-ExampleSite/en_US/-/USD/Pipeline-Start
```

I don't really care about the difference on the URL, but what I care right now is the change from https to http. The same result happened even if I retrieve and print the URL from `ApplicationFrame`. Is there anyone can help explain why it's changed like that, and can provide with workaround to get the original URL in Enfinity (or at least, detect whether the URL is in http or https)? This site uses url rewriting, but I think there's no url writing involved in both URL result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only want the HTTP or HTTPS part, I would suggest not getting the complete URL but just the scheme.
The request scheme defines whether the URL protocol is HTTP or HTTPS.
In code you can get the scheme using `request.getScheme()`
in addition you can get the server name by (the domain of your URL by using `request.getServerName()`
and you can get the port by using `request.getServerPort()`

Comment: Thanks! I know about the `getServerName()`, but I never know about `getScheme()`. I'll try it right away! :)